# Redirect user to app after installation of .mobileconfig

Tags: ios, provisioning

I have been researching this for the past couple of days with moderate success. I am redirecting from the app to a webpage with a WiFI .mobileconfig file (sadly, no way to install this with WebView), the installation goes well but I want to return the user to the app after pressing the DONE button. I have a custom scheme but I do not know how to handle the successful installation i.e. when the user presses DONE. Is there any specific key in the .mobileconfig to do this?

I would greatly appreciate suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the best way here. It is to combine HTML webpage, with the MIMEType for .config files, an iframe that opens the .mobileconfig file and a small JS script that refreshes the page every 5 seconds.